# React Native stuck at Starting: intent after installing the package react-native-google-mobile-ads

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi i am installing the package react-native-google-mobile-ads using the command:

```
npm i react-native-google-mobile-ads
```

But after installing the package i am stuck at command line and build is not creating. Here is the screenshot below.

[react-native-build-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHkNb.png)

But when i uninstall the package the build works sucessfully. Can you please help me what am i doing wrong?

**Here is my react-native app info:**

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4000M CPU @ 2.40GHz
    Memory: 1.42 GB / 15.73 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 8.5.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK:
      AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version     2021.1.0.0 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675
    Visual Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-native: 0.71.11 => 0.71.11
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```